# Should medical conditions be made known to a prospective spouse?

Tags: practical-islam, nikah

Is having a fibroid something I need to let a prospective spouse know about?

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a relationship with a strong foundation in trust and honesty if you're hiding things.

Comment: Questions on religous healing and prescriptions are currently off-topic. Relevant meta: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/853/3487

Comment: Dear @BleedingFingers please read the question properly... the question was edited, so my answer still holds the Du'a. And she isn't asking about religious healing...

Comment: Why do yoy'll keep removing my second question about dua?

Answer (score 1):

As for the Du'a

> Whoever desires the harvest of the Hereafter - We increase for him in his harvest. And whoever desires the harvest of this world - We give him thereof, but there is not for him in the Hereafter any share. (Qur'an 42:20)

As for the proposal, you would like to talk fairly disclosing everything. Cuz if he comes out to know about your condition after marriage, then what?

You can explain, it is no big deal, and if planning to expand family, then you can get that operated just before the moment.

**Tip:** Have patience.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the medical condition.  Some people even agree to [medical examinations](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=173423) prior to marriage.

There's a range of fatawa at IslamWeb asking about the necessity to reveal one's specific medical conditions:

- [infertility](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=39980) (needed);
- [herpes](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=156813) (needed if contagious or repulsive);
- [one testicle](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=92006) (not needed);
- [irregular menses](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=165265) (not needed);
- unspecified "[psychological disease](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=89168)" (needed if it's a "kind of madness");
- [past Hepatitis C](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83970) (not needed);
- [asthma](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85830) (not needed).

---

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/111980) list these general guidelines:

> The basic guidelines with regard to informing a suitor about illness
>   in the prospective wife are as follows:
>
> 1. if the sickness will have any impact on married life and will affect the wife’s ability to fulfil her duties towards her husband and
>      children;
> 2. if it will be off-putting to the husband because of its appearance or smell;
> 3. if it is real and permanent, and is not something imagined or temporary that will disappear with the passage of time or after
>      marriage.

[IslamWeb](http://t.islamweb.org/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=128182) give these guidelines:

> ... if it is a repulsive or contagious disease like leprosy, or is a disease that is dangerous and which may be transmitted to the spouse, or children, like AIDS and the like, then it is not permissible to conceal ...